Xcode doesn't show simulators
I have Xcode 15, and I have iOS 17.0 runtime installed manually through terminal, but still it doesn't show Simulator List, just show get iOS 17.0 button
I checked on platforms and I have iOS 17.0, but I'm trying to download iOS 17 again trough Xcode, why I don't get list of simulators?
I tried to delete derived data, and I tried to copy manually things from iOS dmg
I also tried to reboot the macbook
I tried to list runtimes with xcrun simctl runtime list
== Disk Images ==
-- iOS --
iOS 17.0 (21A328) - 4BFC8A79-C8B1-47CE-B63C-40DB3AE1A321 (Ready)
iOS 17.2 (21C62) - 56D20B12-A33C-45CE-9706-BA5601DE62B6 (Ready)
iOS 17.0 (21A328) - CA6A5939-BB41-40A5-B68C-E670013DA58C (Ready)

Total Disk Images: 3 (16.0G)



"just show get iOS 17.0 button" Yes, you need to do that. You don't see simulators because you have not yet downloaded the iOS 17 SDK. It is a separate item. I do not know what you think "installed manually through Terminal" means; there is no way to do that as far as I know. These images live in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images and you cannot install them except thru Xcode. Whatever you've been doing with the Terminal sounds wrong. A good plan might be to delete the contents of that folder and start over.

Also, I suggest manually deleting all Simulators so that Xcode regenerates them on the next restart. Sometimes the Simulators and the SDKs get "out of sync" after an update. For the current version of Xcode the one you need is 17.4, so you are already well behind.

But when I try to run simulator itself it's working

It is your app that needs the SDK runtime. The simulator is just a host.

Okay, I deleted all old simulators, and installed via xcode, download was successful,  but I still got button iOS 17.0 is not installed

I'm having the same issue myself now. It is evidently spreading.

Have you checked "Minimum Deployments iOS"?

So it turns out that this was due to XProtect payload 132. This has now been updated to XProtect payload 133. So do this:

Quit Xcode.
Delete the contents of top-level /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator. You'll need to provide your admin password.
Restart the computer.
Open Settings and go to Software Update. You should see the computer checking for updates. It will report back that your Mac is up to date, but in fact it will now have downloaded the new XProtect payload.
Confirm that step 4 worked. To do so, hold Option, click the Apple menu, choose System Information, click Software > Installations, and scroll down to the last entry whose type is XProtectPayloads. If it says 133, you're all set.
Launch Xcode and download the simulator SDK. At the end of the download there is a heart-stopping pause, but be patient; it will work.


Just doing the software update works for me

I just updated to Sonoma 14.4.1 (23E224) and still no luck. Confirmed that XProtectPayloads 133 is in my installation.

I am using Xcode 15.3 + iPhone 13 Pro Max iOS 17.4.1 and Xcode is not recognizing the device. Anybody with the same problem?

Restarting my machine helped me. Try that out first before trying anything else.
If it still does not work, then try to delete the Xcode Cache.
Go to System Settings → General → Storage → Developer and then delete "Xcode Caches"

To solve this, I had to restart my machine, go to Apple settings, and then install a pending software command line tool update.  smh

As matt has pointed out, the root cause is said to be payload 132 of XProtect. We can find the list of payloads in System Information:

Apple calls the payload 132 "a macOS system update" in Xcode 15.3 Release Notes and Xcode 15.4 Release Notes as follows:

Known Issues
Some Macs recently received a macOS system update which disabled the simulator runtimes used by Xcode, including the
simulators for iOS, tvOS, watchOS, and visionOS. ...

Apple also shares an accompanying workaround:

Workaround: To resume using the simulator, please reboot your Mac.
After rebooting, check Xcode Settings → Platforms to ensure that the
simulator runtime you would like to use is still installed. If it is
missing, use the Get button to download it again.

The Get button might not work.
In my case, the steps 1, 3, 4 and 5 in matt's answer worked. As fahmi commented, the steps 2 and 6 might be optional in some cases.

I had Xcode 15.4.
I tried to run the app on an old simulator (iOS 15) that I had downloaded before.
The simulators for iOS 15 simply were not visible in the simulators list.
The trick was to go to Window > Devices and Simulators, find the needed device you want to use and switch the option from "Automatic" to "Always".

