Scheme is not testable as iOS 17.4 Not Installed but I did install it
I could not run the app build on Xcode. It keeps saying that I need to install iOS 17.4 but even when I installed it, it still doesn't work. Please screenshot below.


I tried reset and clean build and still nothing.
I installed 17.4 and it still does not let me run the build.
I tried to lower the simulator version to 15.0 and it doesn't even show up in the list.

You should get together with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78372541/xcode-doesnt-show-simulators

Restart my machine helped me.
